# Unity 3D. How do I move the object up when the another object gets on it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the object "ball" that can roll on the surface. There is also the object "platform". So, I need to platform up a certain distance, only when the ball will stop on the platform.

Script on C#.

Answer (score 0):

Honsetly - I don't know about Unity API anything :), but I know that it must have available property "position". So one of the ways to solve you problem - check position of ball in every Update(in comparison with previous position), and when it's position become stable(the same) for a while(some time) - move the platform.

something like:

```
private Vector3 lastPosition;
private stableTime = 0;

public float distThreshold = 0.1;
public float timeThreshold = 0.1;

void FixedUpdate()  {
    if (lastPoistion == null || Vector3.Distance(ball.position, lastPoistion) > distThreshold) {
        lastPosition = ball.position;
        stableTime = 0;
    }
    else
        stableTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (stableTime > timeThreshold)
        platform.MovePoistion()
}
```

Comment: I don't think position needs storing, would it not be possible to just check whether it is stationary, and then have something that triggers only when the two object's meshes are touching?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify 2 things here.

- Is the ball stopped?
- is the ball on the platform

To identify if the ball is stopped simply keep track of it's current speed (using a `speed` property assigned to the ball object). I'm assuming you probably already have this as the player will be controlling the ball? If so, just check that `speed == 0`.

To check whether the ball is on the platform you will need to use colliders. Take a look under 2d or 3d physics (you haven't specified which you are using) and apply some appropriate colliders to both the platform and the ball. You can now programmatically check for collision between the 2 objects. There are plenty of tutorials on object collision so I won't go into it here but [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/collider-2d?playlist=17120) may be a good place to start.